# How can I maintain separate cookie "profiles"? (e.g. work, personal, side gig)

Tags: macos, google-chrome, firefox, browser, cookies

I currently use 3 different browser installs to manage my workflows

- Firefox for QA/Testing
- Chrome for Work
- Safari for Side gig

The only reason I use different browsers is so I can group cookies together, and still have the option for incognito mode as needed.

Is there any way I can have a "cookie jar" associated with each cluster of tabs?

Is there yet another browser that I can use (I'm on OSX) that will assist me?

Comment: Why not use three individual user accounts, one fore each role?

Comment: on windows its possible to open browser as different user. if you want to have different user per tab - that is not possible anywhere as far as I know...how would your browser work with webapps that rely on opening subpages in new tab? "open in new tab" function on every webpage that require login would not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome lets you configure multiple 'persons' in the Chrome settings, each with their own bookmarks, cookies, etc.

There's a convenient button that lets you 'switch person' once you have at least two, but two of these 'persons' can be used in parallel. Each window is associated with one person. Opening a new window will inherit the person from the previous front window.

---

Firefox supports multiple profiles, but I don't know how convenient it is to run multiple instances of Firefox in parallel on OS X. There appear to be addons like Profile Buttons that appear to implement a functionality similar to Chrome's, but I don't know how well they work.